# Python : Extract mails from the string of filenames

Tags: python, regex, string, email, substring

I want to get the mail from the filenames. Here is a set of examples of filenames :

```
string1 = "benoit.m.fontaine@outlook.fr_2022-05-11T11_59_58+00_00.pdf"
string2 = "jeane_benrand@toto.pt_test.pdf"
string3 = "rosy.gray@amazon.co.uk-fdsdfsd-saf.pdf"
```

I would like to split the filename by the parts. The first one would contain the email and the second one is the rest. So it should give for the string2 :

```
['jeane_benrand@toto.pt', '_test.pdf']
```

I try this regex function however it does not work for the second and third string.

```
email = re.search(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", string)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why do you need to use regex if you already split the string and have the email in the first row?

Comment: @YehorSmoliakov I should not know that it contains a "-" or "_" after thr mail. sometimes 
 it has none of them

Comment: Then probably it will be better to split the string by @ character and then parse the domain part of the email. You can split the domain by a dot.

Comment: A problem you might run into is that `-` is a valid character in a domain name. So something like `user@xyz.co-test-one.cab` is a valid email address as a whole as well as being possible to split into `user@xyz.co-test` and `-test-one.cab` or ``user@xyz.co-test` and `-one.cab`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the samples you provided, you can do something like this:

```
import re

strings = ["benoit.m.fontaine@outlook.fr_2022-05-11T11_59_58+00_00.pdf",
           "jeane_benrand@toto.pt_test.pdf",
           "rosy.gray@amazon.co.uk-fdsdfsd-saf.pdf"]

pattern = r'([^@]+@[\.A-Za-z]+)(.*)'

[re.findall(pattern, string)[0] for string in strings]
```

Output:

```
[('benoit.m.fontaine@outlook.fr', '_2022-05-11T11_59_58+00_00.pdf'),
 ('jeane_benrand@toto.pt', '_test.pdf'),
 ('rosy.gray@amazon.co.uk', '-fdsdfsd-saf.pdf')]
```

Mail pattern explanation `([^@]+@[\.A-Za-z]+)`:

- `[^@]+`: any combination of characters except `@`
- `@`: at
- `[\.A-Za-z]+`: any combination of letters and dots

Rest pattern explanation `(.*)`

- `(.*)`: any combination of characters